# Jupyter notebook become RTL after upgrade

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, right-to-left

I created python 3.6 environment in miniconda.
Jupyter notebook is working now right-to-left
[image]

How can I fix it ?

installed packages:

```
ipykernel                 4.7.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
ipython                   6.2.1                    py36_1    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                2.5.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            5.2.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
notebook                  5.2.2                    py36_1    conda-forge
```

Notebook metadata:

```
{
  "celltoolbar": "Edit Metadata",
  "kernelspec": {
    "name": "python3",
    "display_name": "Python 3",
    "language": "python"
  },
  "language_info": {
    "name": "python",
    "version": "3.6.4",
    "mimetype": "text/x-python",
    "codemirror_mode": {
      "name": "ipython",
      "version": 3
    },
    "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
    "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
    "file_extension": ".py"
  }
}
```

Comment: You could try to remove `codemirror_mode` dict

Comment: @HerryPotei: no, that is not what that dict is for. This rather suggests a problem with that textbox edit field.

Comment: how can I check the textbox edit field ?

Comment: I noticed that Jupyter is RTL by default only on Chrome. Direction is LTR on Safari and firefox. Tried to remove any Hebrew regional settings from both Chrome and  Mac O/S but that didn't solve it, so for now I am using another browser with Jupyter (too annoying to switch to RTL with ctrl-shift-F every time). Any help for fixing that for Chrome would be appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

In a notebook:

1. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
2. search `rtl`
3. select togle rtl

Comment: Can you also explain why this would be the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Permanent Solution that worked for me:

On your chrome -> settings -> advanced -> languages

click the arrow to order languages:
[image]

Make sure your first language is a ltr one.

Answer (score 0):

For me the only thing that worked is to remove the RTL language from the list of languages of Chrome.